# How to get last row value of mysql table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to show the active deposit of my user.therefore i want to get last amount user has deposited in his account. but i have new in Laravel . i have tried following but its sums all amount of user not only last one. if you need i will share whole bunch of code here.

```
$data['a_deposit'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id','DESC',LIMIT 1)->take(1)->sum('amount');
```

from here i want to get last amount

```
$data['last_deposit'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(6)->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get only the last ammount, use `value()`:

```
Deposit::where('user_id', auth()->id())->latest('id')->value('amount');
```

If you want to get last amount from already loaded collection:

```
$data['last_deposit'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(6)->get();
```

You can do this:

```
$amount = $data['last_deposit']->first()->amount;
```

Comment: if i want to select amount whose status is 0 then?

Comment: @WaqarAli I don't see any information about status in your question. Please explain it in details.

Comment: sorry . i need status 0 value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latest values in your table you can do something like this:

```
Deposit::latest()->get();
```

or

```
Deposit::latest()->first();
```